# Migrate BuildConfig to Gradle Build Files

Tags: android, gradle

When I build in Android Studio, i get this message:

```
The option setting 'android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true' is deprecated.
The current default is 'false'.
It will be removed in version 9.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You can resolve this warning in Android Studio via `Refactor` > `Migrate BuildConfig to Gradle Build Files`
```

but there is no such option in the Refactor menu

how can I start the Refactor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set manually in the `build.gradle` file

```
 android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=false
```

And make the project again, If there are errors resolve them

I got the error

```
error: cannot find symbol
    int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
                      ^
```

this is my code there:

```
@Override
public void draw(RenderManager renderManager) {
    // Get app version information
    int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

so I passed a context (`activity`) from The GameManager to the CreditsGameScreen, I changed the constructor:

```
public CreditsGameScreen(GameManager gameManager, Context context) {
    super(gameManager);
    mContext = context;
}
```

and used this then:

```
public void draw(RenderManager renderManager) {
    // Get app version information
    int versionCode = getVersionCode(mContext);
    String versionName = getVersionName(mContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be useful to someone.

Right-click in build.gradl Refactor -> Migrate BuildConfig to Gradle Build Files

[image]